# Datatable not rendering html on export

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have added the export option in datatable as:

```
"buttons":[
        {
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'Export to Excel'
        }]
```

I have few columns as anchor tags. On exporting the table, excel file is escaping the html and data exported looks like:
 `<a href=\#" onclick="javascript:dosomething()...`
Any idea to escape html or what could be worng here. TIA.

Comment: Note that you're not "export *as* excel", you're exporting as a plain text csv, which Excel may or may not load (depending on the user's settings) - Excel will see this as a *csv* so will not display as HTML.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet that *demonstrates* the issue.  Adding the latest required script tags etc, to get the export button to show, your code works fine with `<a>` links being converted to text: https://jsfiddle.net/q705fcwa/1/  Include which script tags you're using (ie the version of datatables) and the HTML/json-source of the table you're extending.